# Combine specific column values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following result set:

- Region

  - North
  - South
  - West
- Reason

  - New Admission
  - New Admit
  - Other
- Amount

  - 5.00
  - 6.00
  - 8.00

What I am needing to do is combine just the "New Admission" and "New Admit" values from the Reason column with the corresponding amounts.

So what I would like to end up with is this result set:

- Region

  - North
  - South
  - West
- Reason

  - New Admission/New Admit
  - Other
- Amount

  - 11.00
  - 8.00

The query that I have created to build the first result set is as follows:

```
SELECT Region, Reason, CAST(SUM(Amount) AS Decimal(18,2)) AS Amount FROM Table GROUP BY Region, Reason
```

Just wondering if anyone else has insight into this.  I am using SQL Server 2019

This is a screen shot of the actual data from my table

[image: Actual Data Set]

[image: Needed Data Set]

Comment: Can provide different / more sample data? Your structure is fine, but your sample data / output doesn't group by Region and Reason... It keeps the region split but combines reason and amount which doesn't make sense...

Comment: @dvo yes that is what is making me ask this question.  That is the requirement that they want.  Would it be better just to use a reporting tool?

Comment: you can do it in sql... can you edit your question to include more sample data (raw data from the table) and desired output (your grouped results)?

Comment: I added the actual and needed data sets to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT Region,
       (CASE WHEN Reason IN ('New Admission', 'New Admit') then 'New Admission/New Admit'
             ELSE 'Other'
        END) as Reason,
       CAST(SUM(Amount) AS Decimal(18,2)) AS Amount
FROM Table
GROUP BY Region,
         (CASE WHEN Reason IN ('New Admission', 'New Admit') then 'New Admission/New Admit'
               ELSE 'Other'
          END);
```